# "Name or service not knownstname localhost" error when running Cygwin64

Tags: windows, hadoop, cygwin

I follow the instruction here http://saphanatutorial.com/hadoop-installation-on-windows-7-using-cygwin/ to run Hadoop with Cygwin (64bit). Everything is fine until I run `./start-dfs.sh`. The error is

```
$ ./start-dfs.sh
]tarting namenodes on [localhost
: Name or service not knownstname localhost
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /cygdrive/c/Cygwin64/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-KennyT-datanode-DESKTOP-6I19F66.out                
]tarting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0
: Name or service not knownstname 0.0.0.0
```

I configured the following:

Environmental variables:

---

```
HADOOP_HOME: C:\cygwin64\usr\local\hadoop
JAVA_HOME: C:\Java\bin
Path: C:\cygwin64\usr\local\hadoop\bin;C:\cygwin64\bin; C:\Java\bin
```

hadoop-env.sh:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/cygdrive/c/Java/"
```

Core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
   <property>
       <name>fs.default.name</name>
       <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
       <name>dfs.replication</name>
       <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
       <value>/c:/cygwin64/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-dir/namedir</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
       <value>/c:/cygwin64/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-dir/datadir</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
   <property>
       <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
       <value>yarn</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
   <property>
       <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
       <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
   </property>
   <property>
       <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
       <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

Some notes:

- window 64bit, hadoop 2.7.1
- `java -version` and `hadoop version` both successfully executed. So, I guess no problem with the environment setting.
- sshd service is running, port 22 is open. `ssh localhost` and `telnet localhost 22` both successful.
- I disable IPv6 on Windows but the result was the same.
- In hadoop-env.sh, I replace `"export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"` with `"export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -XX:-PrintWarnings -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"` but no luck.
- `hadoop namenode -format` is successfully.
- I did `dos2unix.exe file` whenever I changed the content of the file
- I run hadoop successfully without cygwin with the above setting. So, I guess there is no problem with settings in these files (core-site, hdfs-site, mapred-site, yarn-site)

I am trying to running Hadoop with cygwin on a single machine. And then widen it to run Hadoop with Cygwin in different machines as a cluster. But I was stuck at this. Please help me.

Comment: You need to change the 0.0.0.0 address to an actual server's IP and localhost might not work in Cygwin. If you have enough memory in your computer, just use a Linux virtual machine

Comment: Thank you for your response. I run server and client in a single machine. So the server ' s address is also localhost. But how to change the address 0.0.0.0 in cygwin?

Comment: I changed it to "127.0.0.1" or my computer ip, which is "192.168.11.35", but the result was the same "Starting namenodes on 127.0.0.1
: Name or service not knownstname 127.0.0.1
localhost: datanode running as process 2436. Stop it first.
]tarting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0
: Name or service not knownstname 0.0.0.0
"

Comment: The error is `Name or service not known`, which means Cygwin doesn't know about `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. And your secondary namenode address needs to be fixed also, not only the datanode address. I would recommend following the official Hadoop documentation or finding another tutorial because Java 1.6 is end of life, and Hadoop 1.2 has long been deprecated. The current version is 2.9, which supports Java 8

Comment: Hadoop has allowed Windows installs since 2.5. For example, here's a tutorial that installs it without using Cygwin. https://www.joe0.com/2017/02/02/how-to-install-a-hadoop-single-node-cluster-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem when trying to start Hadoop but just for data nodes.
After a couple of days I found the problem by tracing the Hadoop scripts and found that you need to set an **space** after each line in ***slaves*** file.

*hadoop-deamons.sh* call *slaves.h* to run slaves one by one

```
exec "$bin/slaves.sh" --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR cd "$HADOOP_PREFIX" \; "$bin/hadoop-daemon.sh" --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR "$@"
```

And *slaves.sh* try to connect in each slave and run `stop datanode` command on that server by the following:

```
# start the daemons
for slave in $SLAVE_NAMES ; do
 ssh $HADOOP_SSH_OPTS $slave $"${@// /\\ }" \
   2>&1 | sed "s/^/$slave: /" &
 if [ "$HADOOP_SLAVE_SLEEP" != "" ]; then
   sleep $HADOOP_SLAVE_SLEEP
 fi
done
```

If you miss space you will happen by something like this:

```
ssh server4"cd /home/xxx/hadoop-2.10.0 ...."
```

Which encounter you with unknown hostname. The correct is:

```
ssh server4 "cd /home/xxx/hadoop-2.10.0 ...."
```

If you edit your files in windows and copy them into linux by widows applications like WinSCP, there is an extra `\r` character that cause a problem in hostname as mentioned above.